# No Bloom with Principled Volume

Tags: lighting, volumetrics

I'm trying to achieve a nice bloom around my lighting with some principled volume fog but I cannot seem to achieve the result I'm looking for (rendering Cycles). Is there something I am doing incorrectly? [image] [image]

[image]

Comment: OK, I see some glow and I'm guessing the upper image is reference, not your rendering? Please be more specific.

Comment: Both images supplied are my renderings

Comment: Any take on why it's not giving me a nice bloom?

Comment: I see some bloom, idk what you are going for.

Comment: Look how for example this picture achieves some nice light streaks from the street lamp https://www.blendernation.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/image7-4.jpg

Comment: To my knowledge this can't be done with meshlights, you have to put additional lamp objects where the glow is supposed to go. In the supplied image, you can see the spot lights of each glow.

Comment: @FrederikSteinmetz Hm, are you sure? I thought that was only the case rendering with Eevee. Most of my light sources are emission shaders. Are you saying they all need to be accompanied by a lamp object?

Comment: @FrederikSteinmetz I've tried experimenting with different lighting objects and none of them produce the kind of bloom I'd like to see in my File

Comment: This sort of thing is better done in the compositor if you're using Cycles.  I'll write something up using fog glow, and maybe crypto mattes if you want a Cycles solution.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I'd like to mention that volumetric scattering does work with emission shaders, not just lamps. Although if you can use lamps, use them instead as they are easier to compute, therefore shorter render times.

The simple answer is to either increase the volumetric density and/or increase the brightness of your lights.

These are objects with emission shaders set to a low strength.

[image]

This is the same scene, but I've replaced the shader on the object on the bottom with another emission shader with a higher strength value.

[image]

As you can see, the scattering is much more visible now. Although, because the light is brighter, the ground is lit more brightly. This is physically accurate, but may not be what you want.

If you want the scattering with low volumetric density and dim lights, here comes the slightly more complex answer which includes view layers.

---

Duplicate all lights and objects that you want to have control over its scattering and move them into a new collection. Replace the new objects with a new emission shader with a higher emission strength, or in the case of lamps, just increase their power. In my case, I'm only going to affect the light at the bottom.

[image]

Now add a new view layer with the button on the top right. In my case, I've called this new layer "Fog Pass". Whilst still viewing the new view layer, enable the Volume Direct option under View Layer Properties > Passes > Light.

[image]

Go back to the main view layer and disable the collection with the stronger lights in.

[image]

Render one frame with <kbd>F12</kbd> and head into the compositor. By default, you will have a compositing workspace as the top, displayed as tabs. Check the Used Nodes button. Add a view node with Add > Output > Viewer. Check Backdrop under View > Backdrop on the right. Anything you plug into the view node, you will see in the background.

You should have a Render Layers node connected to a Composite Node. Duplicate the Render Layers Node and set the View Layer to "Fog pass".

[image]

The VolumeDir output on the "Fog Pass" render layer contains the light scatter and only the light scatter. Mine looks like this :

[image]

Add denoising nodes in places if necessary. Add a Colour Mix node and set to Add. Using the Fac slider, you can add the fake lighting on top of the normally rendered layer without adding any extra light. Emphasis on fake, as this is not physically accurate.

[image]

**Remember to connect your nodes back to the Composite node from the Viewer node.** Otherwise, your render will be black.

---

Image comparison:

[image]

Comment: Appreciate your response, will take a crack at this tomorrow and post results.